# Can I see how much reputation I have with the other farmers?

Tags: story-of-seasons

In order to see events with the other farmers, you need to have a certain amount of reputation with them.  There are specific actions you can undertake to increase them, like shipping stuff, winning field competitions, that sort of thing.

But I have no idea how to see what level I'm at in regards to reputation with them.  I can sorta rough it out from what events I've seen, but that doesn't give me any idea how close I am to the next event.

Comment: Ah, I don't think there's anyway to see that in game. You just have to meet the other requirements and go try to trigger the event.